# How do I write a regular expression to not find match 1430 but match 143851

Tags: regex, regex-negation

```
^(?!1430)(143.*)$
```

Isn't working for me. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I can see your regex working. Please check this link [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/dXy1qa/1)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you clarify your question adding example strings?

Comment: Where are you using the regex?

Comment: With `^(?!1430)` you'd also let [fail eg `14301`...](https://regex101.com/r/UoY4aF/2) If this is the problem, use `$` anchor for *end* inside the lookahead. With @I'-'I's optimization to put the lookahead after `143` and use `\d` for *digit*, it could look like [`^143(?!0$)\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/UoY4aF/4)

Comment: @bobblebubble - And quicker too. `Regex1:   ^143(?!0$)\d*$
Options:  < m >
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.33 s,   328.22 ms,   328222 µs
Matches per sec:   761,679


Regex2:   ^(?!1430$)(143.*)$
Options:  < m >
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.42 s,   421.44 ms,   421435 µs
Matches per sec:   593,211`